# Developer command line for TFS unavailable

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, team-explorer

My developer command line executable file is missing inside MS Visual Studio 2013 folder. I have checked inside `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools` folder. It has only a folder Shortcuts which itself has a shortcut called Build Notifications. 
[You can find the screenshot for the same here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exm3t.png)
How do I fix this issue?

Edit: I already have Team Explorer installed. [You can find that screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4llR.png)

Comment: Did you have multiple VS such as  VS2012/VS2013 installed in your machine?

Comment: Hi kaushik3993, any update on this issue, did my reply helped or gave a right direction?

Comment: Updated the question. Please check.

Comment: The tf command-line utility is located in `<drive>:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE` and is available from the Visual Studio 2013 Command Prompt. Which is IDE folder not the tool folder. And `Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0`  stands for VS2013. which is not visual studio 2012 tag. Please make sure you are searching the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

The tf command-line utility is located in `<drive>:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE` and is available from the Visual Studio 2013 Command Prompt.

Which is **IDE folder** not the tool folder, more details about the command you could refer this [tutorial](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands).

---

You need to install Team Explorer, it's best to install the version of Team Explorer that matches the version of TFS you are using e.g. if you're using TFS 2013 then install Team Explorer 2013.

Check the component of your Visual Studio, if it's lacking of Team Explorer or the Team Explorer is installed incorrect. Try to reinstall it. If the issue is still not fixed, you may have to reinstalled the VS.

Comment: Thanks. I found it.